# How to get a list of lun numbers presented to Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

I have a server 2008r2 machine with many san volumes presented to it.  Is there a way, using powershell preferably, to get a quick list of all the lun numbers presented to it?

Comment: Some SAN manufacturers provide PowerShell cmdlets to administer their devices.  What kind of SANs are attached to the server?

Comment: HP EVA, and a Compellent Storage Center system, but on this server we're just using the stock MPIO that comes with 2008.  It's easy enough to get lun numbers if I go into disk management and right-click each volume, but I have around 30 volumes. I was hoping I could just get a quick list to confirm a particular LUN was visible on that machine.  I've found a number of wmi classes that deal with MPIO, but none so far that offer the LUN number(s) for a particular disk.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Multipath IO (MPIO) for high availability, then you can use the mpclaim.exe utility to get some details about the LUNs. There may be another way to do it using WMI or software from your HBA/SAN provider, but so far the only generic solution I have found is using mpclaim. Even then, it differs slightly from what is listed on other platforms.

For example, In Linux you would use something like [multipath -ll](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/solutions/2643) to get this type of output:

```
[root@localhost ~]# multipath -ll
mpathb (360A9800572D4F6761346536792D6C56) dm-2 NETAPP,LUN
size=150G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=4 status=active
| |- 0:0:1:1 sdg 8:96  active ready running
| `- 1:0:1:1 sdi 8:128 active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  |- 0:0:0:1 sdc 8:32  active ready running
  `- 1:0:0:1 sde 8:64  active ready running
mpatha (360A9800572D4F675034653679386A69) dm-1 NETAPP,LUN
size=150G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=4 status=active
| |- 0:0:0:0 sdb 8:16  active ready running
| `- 1:0:0:0 sdd 8:48  active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  |- 0:0:1:0 sdf 8:80  active ready running
  `- 1:0:1:0 sdh 8:112 active ready running
```

This shows 2 LUNs connected via 4 paths each. Now to get similar information in Windows you would use [mpclaim -v c:\mpio.txt](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619743%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) to create a text file with this output:

```
MPIO Storage Snapshot on Friday, 31 August 2012, at 13:14:45.345

Registered DSMs: 1
================
+--------------------------------|-------------------|----|----|----|---|-----+
|DSM Name                        |      Version      |PRP | RC | RI |PVP| PVE |
|--------------------------------|-------------------|----|----|----|---|-----|
|Microsoft DSM                   |006.0001.07601.17514|0020|0003|0001|030|False|
+--------------------------------|-------------------|----|----|----|---|-----+


Microsoft DSM
=============
MPIO Disk1: 04 Paths, Round Robin, ALUA Not Supported
        SN: 60A9800572D4F6761346536792D6C56                                 
        Supported Load Balance Policies: FOO RR RRWS LQD WP LB

    Path ID          State              SCSI Address      Weight
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0000000077030001 Active/Optimized   003|000|001|001   0
        Adapter: QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter...           (B|D|F: 034|000|000)
        Controller: 46616B65436F6E74726F6C6C6572 (State: Active)

    0000000077030000 Active/Optimized   003|000|000|001   0
        Adapter: QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter...           (B|D|F: 034|000|000)
        Controller: 46616B65436F6E74726F6C6C6572 (State: Active)

    0000000077010001 Active/Optimized   001|000|001|001   0
        Adapter: QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter...           (B|D|F: 006|000|000)
        Controller: 46616B65436F6E74726F6C6C6572 (State: Active)

    0000000077010000 Active/Optimized   001|000|000|001   0
        Adapter: QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter...           (B|D|F: 006|000|000)
        Controller: 46616B65436F6E74726F6C6C6572 (State: Active)

MPIO Disk0: 04 Paths, Round Robin, ALUA Not Supported
        SN: 60A9800572D4F675034653679386A69                                 
        Supported Load Balance Policies: FOO RR RRWS LQD WP LB

    Path ID          State              SCSI Address      Weight
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    0000000077030001 Active/Optimized   003|000|001|000   0
        Adapter: QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter...           (B|D|F: 034|000|000)
        Controller: 46616B65436F6E74726F6C6C6572 (State: Active)

    0000000077030000 Active/Optimized   003|000|000|000   0
        Adapter: QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter...           (B|D|F: 034|000|000)
        Controller: 46616B65436F6E74726F6C6C6572 (State: Active)

    0000000077010001 Active/Optimized   001|000|001|000   0
        Adapter: QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter...           (B|D|F: 006|000|000)
        Controller: 46616B65436F6E74726F6C6C6572 (State: Active)

    0000000077010000 Active/Optimized   001|000|000|000   0
        Adapter: QLogic Fibre Channel Adapter...           (B|D|F: 006|000|000)
        Controller: 46616B65436F6E74726F6C6C6572 (State: Active)

MSDSM-wide default load balance policy: N\A

No target-level default load balance policies have been set.

================================================================================
```

You will notice that in Linux the WWID starts with a 3, but otherwise the SN and WWID should match what is listed on the SAN Controller. You can get additional details for the FC HBA using [fcinfo /details](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17530) or the [Storage Explorer](http://terrytlslau.tls1.cc/2011/08/how-to-find-world-wide-name-wwn-in.html) management console. Server 2012 will add new [MPIO cmdlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826113.aspx), but I haven't had a chance to test those yet.